# ld: cannot find -lgfortranbegin

Tags: fortran, redhat, gfortran

I just installed a code on a cluster with redhat 4.4.6.

When I compile the code, it says:

> ld: cannot find -lgfortranbegin

How can I solve this problem?

Please note that I don't have permissions to install libraries on the cluster.

Comment: If you think the duplicate does not answer your question we need MUCH more information. Are you linking any external libraries? Which exact version of your compiler do you use? Which exact compiler command? Which exact linking command? Gfortran does has not been using libgfortranbegin for many many years. If there is any stray `-lgfortranbegin` anywhere, it is likely just useless.